# Motivation (intuition) about a formal group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, formal-power-series, motivation

A (one-dimensional) formal group over $\mathbb{C}$ is a formal power series $F(x,y)\in\mathbb{C}[[x,y]]$ such that
$$
F(x,y)=x+y + \text{terms of higher order}
$$
$$
F(x,F(y,z))=F(F(x,y),z))
$$

Simplest example is $F(x,y)=x+y$. How did mathematicians come to this concept, what's the motivating background?

Comment: Why is it over $\Bbb C$ and not an arbitrary field $\Bbb F$?

Comment: Probably only for simplicity. This comes from QFT and VOA theory

Comment: One motivation is Lie theory in characteristic $p$, and algebraic groups, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/420328/can-we-use-formal-groups-to-recover-lie-theoretic-representation-theory-in-chara), and read [here](https://ayoucis.wordpress.com/2015/08/10/p-divisible-groups-formal-groups-and-the-serre-tate-theorem/):" Now, formal groups are actually extremely easy to motivate,"